# Nested quotes: RegEx to convert typographically correct cascading quotation

Tags: php, regex

While there are different examples on how to convert similar quotation marks into a typographically correct beginning and ending char by regular expressions, I am still searching for a way to professionally include the following requirement:

A typographically *incorrect* way would be:

> I like the expression **"A traffic light shows "orange" during the switch from yellow to red!"**

Typographically *correct* a nested quote has to be shown in single quotes. That is similar in languages like English, German or French. In German (to clarify the difference in beginning and ending quotation marks) the desired result would be:

> Ich mag die Redewendung **„Eine Ampel zeigt ‚orange‘ beim Umschalten von gelb zu rot!“**

How can I get that result by using regular expressions in PHP?

Comment: Regular expressions, in general, are search patterns. At most, they will be able to tell you whether the quotation mark is the first, second or third. I'm not sure Regex is the way to solve this problem. Especially in English, where you can have contractions in strings like `To quote my friend: "I think she said 'he's here'."`

Comment: Are you looking at 1. replacing straight quotes `" '` with appropriate opening/closing curly quotes `' ' “ ”` in nested content, 2. verifying that single and double quotes are correctly nested, or 3. both?

Comment: The initial problem is to establish precise rules for determining when a double-quote is to be converted to a single-quote, but that's the asker's problem, not ours. Give us the rules and we'll try to help you find a solution.

Comment: An idea to to look for a *word character* after the opening quote, e.g. [`"(?=[\w"])(?>[^"]+|(?0))*"`](https://regex101.com/r/rAhhG5/2) but I'm really not sure if the idea is good at all :p If you can't clearly define the problem as a human being, probably also no regex pattern exsists to solve the issue ;)

Comment: While regex can probably solve this problem (as long as there are 2 nested layers) you probably should not use regex for such a complex task.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: You don't use regex for this. You use a proper string walking function that can properly track depth. Or better yet: someone else absolutely already wrote that code. Look for that, and then use that instead.